# Set XMLDocument as Saxon.Api.XMLDestination

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon

I'm trying to switch from XSLTCompiledTransformation to Saxon XSLTTransformation but I have problems with specifying output destination as XML document to saxon xslt transformation.

This is the old code used for executing xslt transformations:

```
XsltCompiledTransform transform = ... load xslt transform
XsltArgumentList arguments = ... load arguments
var result = new XmlDocument();

using(var xmlReader = new XmlNodeReader(inputXml)) {
    using(var writer = result.CreateNavigator().AppendChild())
        transform.Transform(xmlReader, arguments, writer);
}
```

I've tried to rewrite this to use Saxon library but I have problem with output xmlDocument:

```
XsltTransformer transform = ... load xslt transform
var result = new XmlDocument();

Processor processor = new Processor()
XdmNode input = pro.NewDocumentBuilder().Wrap(inputXml);
transform.InitialContextNode = input;

//tried specifying result as XMLDestination:
transform.Run(result); //getting error

//also tried this:
using(var writer = result.CreateNavigator().AppendChild())
    transform.Run(writer);
```

How can I convert XMLDocument to XmlDestination or how can I setup destination and then convert that result back to XMLDocument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `DOMDestination` http://saxonica.com/html/documentation9.6/dotnetdoc/Saxon/Api/DomDestination.html#DomDestination%28%29, e.g.

```
var result = new DOMDestination();
transform.Run(result);
var resultDoc = result.XmlDocument; // now resultDoc is an XmlDocument
```

Or as an alternative

```
var result = new XmlDocument();
transform.Run(new DOMDestination(result));
```